# Как выполнить кусок JS кода на определенном разрешении экрана?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выполнить инициализацию плагина (JS, jQuery кода), при экране больше 768px?

Вот так решил задачу, но этот действует только если подвигать экран браузером, а мне надо, что бы код сразу действовал, а не ресайзить экран (попробуй это объяснить пользователю =)

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 768) {

        // Инициализация
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 232.5,
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно вызвать функцию сразу + повесить её выполнение на событие `resize`.

```js
(checkAndRepaint)();
window.onresize = checkAndRepaint;

function checkAndRepaint() {
  var $container = $('#container');
  if (window.innerHeight >= 768) {

    // Инициализация
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 232.5,
      itemSelector: '.item'
    });
  } else {
    // Удаление
    $container.masonry('destroy');
  }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте стандартную функцию jquery height.

```
if ($(window).height() >= 768) {

    // Инициализация
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 232.5,
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 768) {

        // Инициализация
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 232.5,
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function functionName() {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 768) {
    // Инициализация
        var $container = $('#container');
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 232.5,
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    }
};
window.onload = functionName; // выполнится при загрузке
window.onresize = functionName; // выполнится при ресайзе
```

Comment: Присвоенная таким образом функция выполнится два раза при загрузке страницы, а при ресайзе выполняться не будет.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, я починил

Comment: Как-бы 、window.onload、 отвечает за выполнение при загрузке стоаницы... один из вариантов, но для меня работает.

Comment: "выполнится два раза при загрузке" а вы пробовали? На разные-же события обработчики повешены